# Programmatically show and hide the popover (MasterViewController) in UISplitViewController (Master-Detail Template)

Tags: ios6, uisplitviewcontroller, show-hide, popover, master-detail

I want to add a button that show/hides the popover, similarly to the one of the DropBox app.
(In both landscape & portrait)

[image: DropBoxAppImageLink]

I have tried many solutions, but at this stage I don't even want to muddy the water with my attempts. If you've done this, or know how to do this, please send me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it appears it's quite simple.

Set some object to be delegate of splitViewController. In my case (I create all viewcontrollers programatically) that was appdelegate.

```
UISplitViewController* splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
        [splitViewController setViewControllers:@[navigationViewController1, navigationViewController2]];
        splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

Implement delegate method to hide master in portrait orientation:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);
}
```

Actually add barButtonItem:

```
    -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
             willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
                  withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
               forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {

            UINavigationController* slaveNavigationViewController = svc.viewControllers[1];
            UIViewController*       slaveViewController = slaveNavigationViewController.viewControllers[0];
            [barButtonItem setTitle:@"Your master title"];
            slaveViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
        }
```

In this method, you get barButtonItem which you customize and add to slaveViewController.

And last one, remove the button in landscape orientation:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    UINavigationController* slaveNavigationViewController = svc.viewControllers[1];
    UIViewController*       slaveViewController = slaveNavigationViewController.viewControllers[0];
    [barButtonItem setTitle:@"Drops"];
    slaveViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: And what if I want to hide the MasterView when in landscape?

Comment: To hide the MasterView in portrait and landscape just return yes in -(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return YES;
}

Comment: Thank you Norman G, but what I want should be more like the DropBox app: In Landscape mode, when the pop-over is displayed, it should not go OVER the detail, but the detail window should rather resize to fit the remaining space. Any idea on how to to this?

Comment: The problem that I have it that 
"(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation" only fires when the device's orientation is changed by physically rotating it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler, undocumented way to do it.  For an existing UIButton:

```
[button addTarget: theSplitViewController action: @selector(toggleMasterVisible:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This target/action are the same as for the barButtonItem sent in the willHideViewController function.